# Well ordered sets: limit case of a singleton.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently trying to come to grips with well ordered sets.

I've been told that

(1) N ( the set of natural numbers) is well ordered. 
(2) every subset of a well ordered set is well ordered.

From this should follow that any singleton having a natural number as element is well ordered, for example {0} or {10}.

Is it correct? How to show that {10} satisfies the conditions for being well ordered as stated in the definition of this concept?

Comment: How (precisely) do you define a well-ordered set?

Comment: @Brian. S is well ordered iff every non empty subset of S has a first element.

Comment: @RayLittleRock Actually *every* singleton $\{x\}$ is well-ordered by the relation $=$. It is not necessary that $x$ is a (natural) number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. A set is well-ordered if it is totally ordered and every non-empty subset has a minimum. In the case of for example $\{10\}$ we see this has one non-empty subset which is $\{10\}$ which has minimum $10$.

If we assume (1) and (2) are true as you may, we only have to note that $\{10\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. By (1) $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered and by (2) $\{10\}$ is also well-ordered as subset of a well-ordered set.

Comment: @FlorisClaasens. Thanks. May I ask you to add a little formal proof of the fact that 10 qualifies as minimum? I ask this because this assertion is a bit counterintuitive, inasmuch as "first" seems, in natural language,  to presuppose a plurality and a comparison; in such a way that it is difficult to believe that a single element can be called  " first"

Comment: Minimum is defined as the smallest element of a set, i.e. $10$ is the minimum of $\{10\}$ if for all $x\in \{10\}$ we have $10\leq x$. In this case all we need to check is that $10\leq 10$ which is true. Honestly, I'd say that the fact that $10$ is the minimum of $\{10\}$ is so evident it requires no proof.

Comment: @FlorisClaasens. Thanks for this proof.